# "undefined method path" error installing RubyGems

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

I have installed Ruby v1.9.2, and (according to the instructions on http://rubyonrails.org/download) I am trying to install Gems.  I've downloaded the 1.4.2 zip from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126, but when I run setup.rb, I get the following error/trace:

```
C:\temp\rubygemsInstall\rubygems-1.4.2\rubygems-1.4.2>setup.rb
C:/temp/rubygemsInstall/rubygems-1.4.2/rubygems-1.4.2/lib/rubygems/source_index.
rb:62:in `installed_spec_directories': undefined method `path' for Gem:Module (N
oMethodError)
        from C:/temp/rubygemsInstall/rubygems-1.4.2/rubygems-1.4.2/lib/rubygems/
source_index.rb:52:in `from_installed_gems'
        from C:/temp/rubygemsInstall/rubygems-1.4.2/rubygems-1.4.2/lib/rubygems.
rb:914:in `source_index'
        from C:/temp/rubygemsInstall/rubygems-1.4.2/rubygems-1.4.2/lib/rubygems/
gem_path_searcher.rb:83:in `init_gemspecs'
        from C:/temp/rubygemsInstall/rubygems-1.4.2/rubygems-1.4.2/lib/rubygems/
gem_path_searcher.rb:13:in `initialize'
        from C:/temp/rubygemsInstall/rubygems-1.4.2/rubygems-1.4.2/lib/rubygems.
rb:873:in `new'
        from C:/temp/rubygemsInstall/rubygems-1.4.2/rubygems-1.4.2/lib/rubygems.
rb:873:in `searcher'
        from C:/temp/rubygemsInstall/rubygems-1.4.2/rubygems-1.4.2/lib/rubygems.
rb:495:in `find_files'
        from C:/temp/rubygemsInstall/rubygems-1.4.2/rubygems-1.4.2/lib/rubygems.
rb:1034:in `load_plugins'
        from C:/temp/rubygemsInstall/rubygems-1.4.2/rubygems-1.4.2/lib/rubygems/
gem_runner.rb:84:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from C:/temp/rubygemsInstall/rubygems-1.4.2/rubygems-1.4.2/setup.rb:25:i
n `<main>'
```

I am running Windows Server 2008 R2 - please post a comment if there is any other relevant info.

How do I get around this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) includes rubygems already, so you don't have to install it separately. I'm assuming you're using RubyInstaller because that's what the rubyonrails.org page links you to if you click on the Windows link, but there is more information on the [RubyInstaller page in the Help section](http://rubyinstaller.org/).

What happens if you go to a cmd prompt and do "gem list"?

Comment: Correct and correct! `gem list` confirms that Gems is installed. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it! The RubyInstaller google group is also a good resource if you get stuck with any other windows+ruby problems: http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of rubygems aren't completely compatible with Ruby 1.9.2.  I realize the OP discovered that rubygems was already installed, but for those who still need to install it, all you need to do is downgrade to Ruby 1.8.7 and then it should work properly.  This is where a tool like [RVM](https://rvm.io) really comes in handy.